# Finding the min distance MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find the min distance between (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 for a particular macId and timeStamp. I'm trying to find a nearest possible gate
location for an individual at one particular instance of time. So, the query should return one unique value of user at one instance of time that is min to the GATE location.

The data set looks like:

```
   X1       Y1    TimeStamp    MACID               X2    Y2      Gate
| 5618  | 5303 |1 12:22:02 | 54:ea:a8:53:5b:eb | 5844  | 5377  | C24
| 5848  | 5046 |1 12:22:02 | 54:ea:a8:53:5b:eb | 5844  | 5377  | C18
| 6094  | 5464 |1 12:22:02 | 54:ea:a8:53:5b:eb | 5844  | 5377  | C17
| 6021  | 6540 |1 13:09:48 | 48:5a:3f:6a:01:b9 | 6210  | 6801  | C23
| 6366  | 7036 |1 13:09:48 | 48:5a:3f:6a:01:b9 | 6210  | 6801  | C14
| 6366  | 7036 |1 13:09:48 | 48:5a:3f:6a:01:b9 | 6210  | 6801  | C13
```

The result set should look like below:

```
   X1       Y1    TimeStamp    MACID               X2    Y2      Gate
| 5848  | 5046 |1 12:22:02 | 54:ea:a8:53:5b:eb | 5844  | 5377  | C18
| 6021  | 6540 |1 13:09:48 | 48:5a:3f:6a:01:b9 | 6210  | 6801  | C23
```

I have tried this below query but not working:

```
select min((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2), macID, timeStamp from maptable 
groupbymacID, timeStamp
```

I also tried using self joins but seems completely wrong.

May I know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Your result seems to be returning the `MAX` instead of `MIN`.

Comment: Thanks for correcting, but I'm looking for logic how to get the results. Min and Max doesn't make any difference though

Comment: "I have tried this below query but not working:" - why and what is *not working*?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'min((snapX- poiX)*(snapX-poiX)+(snapY - poiY)*(snapY -poiY)) groupby timeStamp, ' at line 1 : this is the error I'm getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this query:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM maptable m, (
  SELECT TimeStamp, macid, MIN(POW((x2-x1), 2) + POW((y2-y1), 2)) mindist
  FROM maptable
  GROUP BY TimeStamp, macid
) a
WHERE m.TimeStamp = a.TimeStamp AND m.macid = a.macid
 AND POW((x2-x1), 2) + POW((y2-y1), 2) = a.mindist;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7979/6

But note that it does not return one row per macid and date, because in your input data the two final rows are the same, so the min distance is the same for gates C13 and C14

Comment: the query seems to be working for mysql 5.6, but not for  version                 " 5.5.44-0 ubuntu0.12.04.1". Is there any major changes that needs to be done

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What's the error? I tested it with MySQL 5.5 with no problem

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo while replicating the query. I'm waiting for results to be out and will mark it as answered.